# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (440)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

When my asp.net web application is trying to access another webservice from the CodeBehind, I get the error message "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (440) 440."
In the Chrome dev tools, I extracted the type of exception: "System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException"

With an older version of the remote webservice that I'm contacting, it seems to work fine. The only thing that changed that I can think of is my IDE version. I recently switched from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015. Is there anything that changed in regards to the Webservice/Service reference technology?
The exception is thrown when the result is returned from the WebMethod, the .net Framework also didn't change since then.

When it comes to the error code, I'm not sure if it's a HTTP error code, 440 seems to mean that posting is not allowed. I'm running an IIS7 on the test servers and IIS Express version 10 as it seems from the HTTP request.

Server stack trace:

```
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

The stack trace indicates some kind of proxy related calls, but no proxy is used for this call.

Please let me know if you require further details, thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

May be there is a difference in both version's web.config file.

1. Create new project in latest version.
2. Get web.config of newly created project and apply your existing web.config file's settings within that.
3. Upload web.config file again.

This will solve issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, should I do this for the remote web service project or the project in which I'm accessing the remote web service?

Comment: Update: I just did this for the remote web service project and I had to remove several entries from this web.config to even get it to work. After replacing the web.config file, the same issue appeared.

Comment: If both project were developed in old then you should do this for both projects as both projects' web.config files has different config entries. You need to compare though.

Comment: OK thanks, I'll give it a try and update the status afterwards. Any other suggestions if that doesn't work?

Comment: It will definitely work. I faced same issue earlier with VS2008 and VS2012. I solved in this way.

Comment: It did not work for me. Also I had to change so many lines to be able to compile that there wasn't much left of the VS2015 web.config base file.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'll try to provide the files this week!